# Static routing in node express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Im using a set of static routes in Node Express and are experiencing a very strange phenomenon.

The routing is set up so that `'/list/*'` and `'/setup/*'` gets to different html-files where the directories are used kind of as storage id, for example updating info on the page `url/setup/12345` would store info in `12345`.

To be able to load scripts and such there is also route with regex matching `/assets/` to allow `url/setup/assets/script.js` to be reached without routing to `setup.html` with a new storage id.

My problem is that this works for `url/setup/assets/script.js` but not for `url/list/assets/script.js` even though they have identical routings.

---

Edit:

Navigating to `url/list/assets/script.js` leads to `list.html` (unwanted behaviour)

Navigating to `url/setup/assets/script.js` leads to `script.js` (wanted behaviour)

---

Any ideas on why '/list/*'` wont work?

Here are my static routes:

```
app.use(/assets/, express.static(wwwPath));

app.use('/list/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('list.html', { root: wwwPath });
});

app.use('/setup/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('setup.html', { root: wwwPath });
});
```

Comment: You'd be a lot better off if you don't create conflicting rules where more than one rule matches the same path.  Right now, both `'/list/*'` and `/assets` match the URL it does not work for.  Probably you're a lot better off creating one static rule for `/setup/assets` and another one for `/list/assets`.  Then, everything will be nice and clear with no overlap, no conflicts.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "`/list/*` wont work"?

Comment: @Arbel - Navigating to url/list/assets/script.js leads to list.html (unwanted behaviour)
Navigating to url/setup/assets/script.js leads to script.js (wanted behaviour)

Comment: @jfriend00 Yepp, probably. But without going into details, I need this to work.

Comment: @Presidenten - Well, I'd suggest you go into the details if you want help because it doesn't work the way you're trying and there are good reasons for that.  Ambiguous and conflicting routes are just a really bad idea and I think express.static does not work the way you expect it to.  You probably need to clean up the design to match the way routes work the best.  If you want to see why you end up with `list.html` when you don't want it, then just set a breakpoint in `express.static()` and watch how it matches that one.

Comment: @jfriend00, your original comment got me thinking on other solutions and I managed to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use custom middleware. Here are the new routes:

```
var requestParser = function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.originalUrl.indexOf('/assets/') >= 0) {
        var assetPath = path.join(wwwPath,  req.path.slice(req.url.indexOf('/assets/')));
        fs.stat(assetPath, function(error, stat){
            if(stat && stat.isFile()) {
                res.sendFile(assetPath);
            }
            else{ 
                res.status(404).send('<h1>404</h1>');
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
};

app.use(requestParser);

app.use('/list/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('schema.html', { root: wwwPath });
});

app.use('/setup/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('setup.html', { root: wwwPath });
});
```