# Content Security Policy issues with new form

Tags: node.js, reactjs, content-security-policy

What is the easiest way for me to set the content security policy for a new form I am using? I have a frontend to backend form working for my registration but this form is a lot more complicated and is throwing me the errors below. I am aware this is to do with webpack and I have tried inserting code into my publ;ic index.html file which just stopped the page from rendering.

[image]

[image]

Would this have anything to do with my CORS settings in the backend? I have the below code which references headers and the I have been getting error messages about setting headings in other forms that I am having the same issues with.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header(
        'Access-Control-Allow-headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
    );
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The errors described have nothing to do with your CORS settings in the backend. They are related to CSP (Content-Security-Policy) header, which you, it would seem, do not use. But for nonexistent pages node JS is published CSP header on its own.

Pay attention to status code `404 Not Found`. If you do not handle this kinds of errors, nodeJS uses own `finalhandler` to carry out of those by default.
Last versions of this `finalhandler` publish the CSP `default-src 'none';` all the nitty-gritty is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64614336/why-do-i-get-the-default-src-none-content-security-policy-error-on-react-pw/64631888#64631888).

Looks like you do not serve routes to root `/` folder in you server config, therefore `/favicon.ico` and similar urls are not found -> `finalhandler` publishes `default-src 'none';` -> you observe CSP violation in the browser console (along with the 404 not found messages).

You have to add into `server.js` something like that:

```
app.use(express.static('client/public'));
app.get("/favicon.ico", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "/favicon.ico"));
});
```

The above will solve the issue with "`/favicon.ico` Not Found", for other "non existent" Urls you need to add routes too.

Comment: Cheers, for the static url address do I direct it to the location from the server.js file in my backend?

Comment: Yes, default file name for start app should be `server.js` if you did not redefine it. And have a look, at least breefly, [Routing in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) and [Custom static routing Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36395563/static-routing-in-node-express). May be you'll find a better examples how to make routing.