# default-src Content Security Policy errors showing on failed form submit in React

Tags: reactjs, express, content-security-policy

I have been trying to get rid of a number of CSP errors when I make a form submission but the number keep increasing. I thought I had handled the fav.icon error by directing express to the public folder in the front-end however it is still flagging with the default-src errors. On reading about default-src errors I also found into about a csp.json however when I added this the same errors have been showing. **Where can I access the default-src or set this in React?** i know fav.icon is the React logo so I am not so concerned about that but it looks really messy in my console and I am not sure if this causes problems elsewhere in my app.

CSP.JSON

```
{
  "dev": {
    "default-src": ["'self'"],
    "style-src": [
      "'self'",
      "https://*.google.com"
    ]
  },
  "prod": {
    "default-src": "'self'",  // can be either a string or an array.
    "style-src": [
      "'self'"
    ],
    "connect-src": [
      "'self'",
      "https://localhost:5002/"
    ]
  }
}
```

backend showing express where my fav.icon file is

```
app.use(express.static('../WebApp/sustainable-scuba-web-app/public/'));
app.get("/favicon.ico", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "/favicon.ico"));
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you have to figure out how the policy is delivered to web page.
   CSP can be delivered in 2 ways:

- with HTTP header, tutorial how to check is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629). Pay attantion to `Status Code` field, because for 403/404/50X error pahes the CSP header can be published by [finalhandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66879099/content-security-policy-issues-with-new-form/66884137#66884137) middleware.
- with the `<meta http-equiv='content-security-policy' content='...'>` meta tag. You can check it just by reviewing HTML code.

2. `CSP.JSON` is related to [react-csp package](https://github.com/YIZHUANG/react-csp#user-content-install), it publishes CSP via meta tag. Therefore if you already have CSP delivered with HTTP header (see para 1 above), you will add a second CSP, which can't mitigate the first one.

After found how CSP is delivered and what directives it have, you will have a clue where it's published.

If CSP is delivered with HTTP header (from the server side) - it [can be either](https://csplite.com/csp211/#CSP_ExpressJS) Helmet middleware (90%), `express-csp-header` package, `simple-csp` package or `Content-security-policy` package. Or even native `res.set(field [, value])` / `res.header(field [, value])` calls.

If CSP is delivered with meta tag, more probability it's specific React packages/plugins like `react-csp`.

Most of similar cases are related to Helmet middleware, which since version 4 publishes its own default CSP out of a blue.